# Has there ever been an NBA game in which one team did not score a single three-pointer?

Tags: trivia, basketball, statistics, nba

Does someone know of an example of an NBA game in which one team did not score a single three-pointer? Did this ever happen?

Answer (score 8):

First, the three-point line was introduced in the NBA for the 1979-1980 season<sub>[(1)](http://espn.go.com/nba/playoffs/2015/story/_/id/12993098/nba-35-year-war-3-pointer)</sub>. Therefore, every game before that season did not include a single three-pointer.

> Does someone [know] of an example of [an] NBA game in which one team did not score ... a single ... three-pointer?

Between the 1979-1980 NBA season and the 2015-2016 NBA season, this has happened 11,253 times according to Basketball Reference's Team Game Finder<sub>[(2)](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player=&match=game&lg_id=NBA&year_min=1964&year_max=2016&team_id=&opp_id=&is_range=N&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&best_of=&team_seed=&opp_seed=&team_seed_cmp=eq&opp_seed_cmp=eq&game_num_type=team&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_location=&game_result=&is_overtime=&c1stat=fg3&c1comp=eq&c1val=0&c2stat=&c2comp=gt&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=gt&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=gt&c4val=&order_by=date_game&order_by_asc=&offset=11200)</sub>.

A few interesting points to note:

- The number of three point attempts per game has steadily increased since its introduction<sub>[(1)](http://espn.go.com/nba/playoffs/2015/story/_/id/12993098/nba-35-year-war-3-pointer)</sub>.
- Between the 2013-2014 NBA season and the 2015-2016 NBA season (which includes three seasons), the number of times a team did not score a single three-pointer in a game is 6 (including once during the entire 2013-2014 NBA season)<sub>[(3)](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player=&match=game&lg_id=NBA&year_min=1964&year_max=2016&team_id=&opp_id=&is_range=N&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&best_of=&team_seed=&opp_seed=&team_seed_cmp=eq&opp_seed_cmp=eq&game_num_type=team&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_location=&game_result=&is_overtime=&c1stat=fg3&c1comp=eq&c1val=0&c2stat=&c2comp=gt&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=gt&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=gt&c4val=&order_by=date_game&order_by_asc=)</sub>.
- During the 2012-2013 NBA season, the number of times a team did not score a single three-pointer in a game is 5.
- Before the 2012-2013 NBA season, a team not scoring a single three-pointer in a game was more common.